# Entity Translation - permission for translating only own nodes of specific content type

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I use the Entity Translation module to translate my content type "profile". With the content type "profile" an authentificated user can create a profile and then translate some of the nodes' fields. My problem is that I can't figure out how to give the authenticated role the permission to translate only their own profile.

I can only select the permissions "*Translate any Entity*" or "*Translate entities of type node*". When I activate the "workflow permission" in Entity Translation's settings, I can additionally select "*Edit shared values*" and "*Edit original values*".

However, the user should be able to translate only his own content type "profile".

Does somebody know how to achieve this?